# Is there an accelerator key solution to give TrackBar focus

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, trackbar, acceleratorkey

I am coding in C# and NET but I do not think that really matters to the question.

Assume that I have a Button whose tab stop is 0 and it gets focus when the form opens.
Assume that I have a Label (text = "&My text:", tab stop = 1)
Assume that I have a TextBox (tab stop = 2; the tab stop immediately follows the label' s tab stop)
When the form opens the button has focus but if I press <ALT+m> (the accelerator key for the label) the TextBox gets focus.

Assume that there is also a TrackBar (slider) on the form. How do I use an accelerator key to change the focus from the Button or the TextBox to the TrackBar?

I tried the obvious - immediately preceding the TrackBar in the tab order with the label which has an accelerator key (as works for text fields) but it did not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, operator error - the obvious solution was right. Somehow my preceding label's tab stop was not set appropriately.